# API to access dictionary popover in OS X?

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-snow-leopard, osx-lion

I've been trying to find this in the developer documentation, but having trouble so hoping somebody could answer it or point me in the right direction.

In OS X apps using (I think) Core Text, you can hover over a word and type ctrl + cmd + d (or in Lion triple-finger tap as a gesture) to look up a dictionary definition via popover.

Is there a public API to insert additional information into that popover?

Answer (score 1):

[Apples Dictionary Services Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/userexperience/Reference/DictionaryServicesRef/index.html) offers `HIDictionaryWindowShow(_:_:_:_:_:_:_:)`. This function opens a window containing the definition of your phrase.